# To-do list html page using local storage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I need to write a page that asks the user to enter a task, and the color that he wants the task to be having ... tried some codes but i'll show you my last try, the problem is that the color of all tasks gets updated with the new value OR it does't apply the given color at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5 Canvas Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">



    function set(){
    var cont = document.getElementById("todo").value;
    var color = document.getElementById("bg").value;
    localStorage.setItem("task", cont);
    localStorage.setItem("preferences-bgcolor", color);
    //alert(localStorage.getItem('preferences-bgcolor'));
    showDiv();
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="b">


    <label>ADD A TASK TO YOUR TO DO LIST:</label>
    </br>
    Task:<input type="text" name="task" id="todo"><br>
    Color:<input type="text" list="list" id="bg">
        <datalist id="list">
            <option value="White">
            <option value="Green">
            <option value="Blue">
        </datalist>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="set()">

    <div id="content">


    </div>


  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">


  function showDiv(){

  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML+="<p style='localStorage.getItem('preferences-bgcolor')'>"+localStorage.getItem('task')+"</p></br>";
  //document.getElementById("content").style.color = localStorage.getItem('preferences-bgcolor');

  }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `style='localStorage.getItem('preferences-bgcolor')'` That's not going to work.

Comment: Why? How can i make it work ? I just retrieved the value from localStorage which has the color the user chose

Answer (score 0):

Change `style='localStorage.getItem('preferences-bgcolor')'` to

`"<p style='" + localStorage.getItem('preferences-bgcolor') + "'>"`